# Why can't I use some flags in combination for my SDL window?

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, window, sdl

I need my window to contain the `SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI` and `SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL` flag but when i tried to implement that my window would just ignore the `SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI` flag. To double check I tried using them separate and both worked. Does anybody know why?

I tried doing this:

```
SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("OpenGL", 
                                      SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 
                                      SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 
                                      WIDTH, 
                                      HEIGHT, 
                                      SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
```

But when I moved my mouse while printing the mouse position to the console I noticed that my window ignored the `SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI` flag.

Comment: What platform are you on?  If you are on Mac, did you set NSHighResolutionCapable Info.plist property to YES?

Comment: I am using Linux.